# How does Madden-Julian Oscillation (MJO) affects Tropical cyclones, onset of monsoon and the ENSO Cycle?

Tags: meteorology, atmosphere

How does Madden-Julian Oscillation (MJO) affects Tropical cyclones, onset of monsoon and the ENSO Cycle?

I cant seem to find any "general explanation" (concept wise) for how MJO affects the TC, monsoon and ENSO cycle

Comment: Please read [What is the MJO, and why do we care](https://www.climate.gov/news-features/blogs/enso/what-mjo-and-why-do-we-care), and then refine your question. It will also help if you read up on teleconnections.